# Converting a WebCamTexture into IplImage of OpenCV gives me a grey image

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, emgucv

As the title suggest, I'm using Emgucv with Unity to perform a face detection. 
Inside the package downloaded from the website there is an example that, given a Texture2D, returns an image with a rectangle on the face of the subject represented.
Everything seems easy but when I try to detect a face in real time comes up a problem. Converting a WebCamTexture into a Texture2D everything seems to work fine but when I try to convert the Texture2D into an Image (class that wraps the IplImage of OpenCV) using TextureConverter (given from Emgucv) it gives me a grey image. 
Here is the simple code I use:

```
void Start()
{
    WebCamDevice[] devices = WebCamTexture.devices;
    int cameraCount = devices.Length;

    if (cameraCount == 0)
    {
        Image<Bgr, Byte> img = new Image<Bgr, byte>(640, 240);
        CvInvoke.PutText(img, String.Format("{0} camera found", devices.Length), new System.Drawing.Point(10, 60),
                         Emgu.CV.CvEnum.FontFace.HersheyDuplex,
                         1.0, new MCvScalar(0, 255, 0));
        Texture2D texture = TextureConvert.ImageToTexture2D(img, FlipType.Vertical);

        this.guiTexture.texture = texture;
        this.guiTexture.pixelInset = new Rect(-img.Width/2, -img.Height/2, img.Width, img.Height);
    }
    else
    {
        webcamTexture = new WebCamTexture(devices[0].name);

        baseRotation = transform.rotation;
        webcamTexture.Play();
        data = new Color32[webcamTexture.width * webcamTexture.height];
        CvInvoke.CheckLibraryLoaded();
    }

    tx2d = new Texture2D(webcamTexture.width, webcamTexture.height);
    tx2d.UpdateExternalTexture(webcamTexture.GetNativeTexturePtr());

    String fileName = "haarcascade_frontalface_alt2";
    filePath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, fileName + ".xml");

    {
        //updateTextureWithString("start move cascade xml");
        TextAsset cascadeModel = Resources.Load<TextAsset>(fileName);

        #if UNITY_METRO
        UnityEngine.Windows.File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, cascadeModel.bytes);
        #else
        File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, cascadeModel.bytes);
        #endif
        //updateTextureWithString("File size: " + new FileInfo(filePath).Length);
    }
}

void Update()
{
    if (webcamTexture != null && webcamTexture.didUpdateThisFrame && tx2d != null)
    {           
        //OLD: this method is very expansive. Is preferable to use the reference to the array of pixels -> tx2d.UpdateExternalTexture(webcamTexture.GetNativeTexturePtr());
        //tx2d.SetPixels(webcamTexture.GetPixels());
        //tx2d.Apply();

        img = TextureConvert.Texture2dToImage<Rgba, Byte>(tx2d, FlipType.Vertical);

        using (CascadeClassifier classifier = new CascadeClassifier(filePath))
        using (Image<Gray, Byte> gray = img.Convert<Gray, byte>())
        {
            //updateTextureWithString("classifier create ok");
            Rectangle[] faces = null;
            try
            {                       
                faces = classifier.DetectMultiScale(gray);
                Debug.Log("faces: " + faces.Length.ToString());

                //updateTextureWithString("face detected");
                foreach (Rectangle face in faces)
                {
                    CvInvoke.Rectangle(img, face, new MCvScalar(0, 255, 0));
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.Log (e.ToString());
                //updateTextureWithString(e.Message);
                return;
            }


            //updateTextureWithString(String.Format("{0} face found on image of {1} x {2}", faces.Length, img.Width, img.Height));
        }

        renderer.material.mainTexture = TextureConvert.ImageToTexture2D(img, FlipType.None);    
    }
```

Note that if I use the code commented as OLD, the Texture2D is converted fine.

I have a second question now. I noted that if I give an Image over than 512x512 to the Classifier Unity crashes and no errors are "thrown out".

Can someone help me?